# mailgun email reaching gmail's promotion tab not primary

Tags: email, mailgun

I have a website and I am gonna blast a mass email, all testing process are working as excepted But the only issue is, its reaching promotion tab on gmail instead of reaching primary tab.

I searched for a day and lot of solution is, Meed to move that email from promotion tab to primary tab. This is not at all possible. I am gonna blast it for one million new users. This is only one time emails not a regular system to let them mark it.

I checked my inbox and lot ofpromotions are reacing my primary tab the only differecne is, its showing the mailing list in info tab like "mailing list: mohan.support.domain.com Filter messages from this mailing list".

Thanks if there are any good trick to reach primary tab.

Comment: Offtopic. We're not here to help spammers blast their crap out.

Comment: got it. But I think its a technique not only for spammers. Also it will be a good trick to most of them not just a spammers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to appear in the primary inbox unless the user moves you themselves.

I'm not sure the algorithm that Google uses to classify promos vs personal mail. Maybe it recognizes multiple Gmail users getting the same message, maybe it is the email address being recognized as a company or bulk sending address. However it is, it is similar to loading images in many clients. The recipient needs to enable your images to load by default by adding you as a safe sender. Similar concept, they need to set you to their primary box for you to gain that privilege.

Comment: I got it John. But there might be a way because I am receiving too many promotion emails on my primary tab. Thanks for your response.

Comment: They may just be lucky that Google hasn't figured out what they are yet. I'm certain if there was a technique, I would have heard of it by now.

Comment: Here is a related article: http://marketingland.com/gmail-inbox-tabs-promotions-primary-56500